# Adding UIView as subview of app's main window

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display a UIView on top of other views, no matter what view is currently displayed. So I created the following method in custom class that is not related to any views:

```
 -  (void) showLoading {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 100, 100)];
    [redView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[appDelegate window] addSubview: redView];
}
```

The view is not displayed when the method is called. However it is displayed if I rotate device, so screen orientation is changed. I guess that I should reload view somehow, but at this point I'm stuck. Could you please help me?

Comment: You don't want to add a view to the AppDelegate, you want to add it to your app's main window.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for noticing. I corrected it.

Comment: What happens if you `bringToFront`? Also, it makes a difference _when_ you call `showLoading` - when are you calling it?

Comment: `bringToFront` doesn't help. And `showLoading` is called asynchronously, so I don't really know when it is called. I assume that it can be called at any time.

Comment: Is `showLoading` being called from the main thread?

Comment: No, it isn't called from main thread. The idea is to interrupt user from using an app when it needs t load updates from server, and make him wait while it is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, dtrotzjr, for good question. The problem was that the method was called from background thread. Here is the solution:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 100, 100)];
        [redView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [[appDelegate window] addSubview:redView];
    });
```

Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer so others can quickly see the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a AlertViewController and present that on top of any view controller, you can even make this AlertViewController to be transparent.

```
self.parentVC = someVC;/*this should be the VC over which you want to present the alert VC */
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self setTransitioningDelegate:someDelegate];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.parentVC presentViewController:self
                                animated:YES
                              completion:^{
                              }];
});
```